# Should \minipage restore the default definition of \@par?

Tags: lists, minipage, latex-base

I came across the issue hinted at in the title while I was 
reflecting on
[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306937)
(“Irregular spacing around a user-defined environment”) and
[its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307014).

The `\@endparenv` command is called by all “list-making”
environments (via `\endtrivlist`) to ensure that “LaTeX begins a
new paragraph if and only if you leave a blank line after the
`\end` command” (quoted from `ltlists.dtx`).  It does so by
applying a “temporary change” (in the sense specified by
`ltpar.dtx`) to the meaning of `\par` at the very end of the
environment itself.  On the other hand, “list-making”
environments also need to apply a “long-term change” to `\par`
during their initialization phase, more precisely when
`\@trivlist` is executed (see `ltlists.dtx` 2015/05/10, lines
78–86).  The mechanism devised in `ltpar.dtx` for changing the
meaning of `\par` ensures that these two changes work together in
a consistent way when “list-making” environments are nested
within one another.

However, I was wondering whether this mechanism behaves
correctly, in the current LaTeX kernel, also when a list
environment appears inside a `minipage` that is itself nested
within another list environment: indeed, it seems reasonable
that, in this case, the `minipage` should act as a “sandbox”,
“shielding”, so to speak, the inner environment from the outer
one; but this is not what currently happens, as the following
example shows.  Actually, the example doesn’t directly use a list
environment, but `flushleft`, which, however, is implemented by
means of `\trivlist`; this is done to remain closer to the
situation discussed in
[the aforementioned question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306937).

You are invited to compile the following code and to examine its
output, as well as the source code itself, before reading on.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.

\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}     % Just to check that the source is still pure,
                                 % 7-bit-clean ASCII when you execute it, as it
                                 % was when I wrote it.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@SHOW[1]{%
    \texttt{\char\escapechar #1} $\Longrightarrow$
        \texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname #1\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand*\SHOW{%
    \myNL\@SHOW{par}\myNL\@SHOW{@par}%
}
\newcommand*\MyParShape{%
    \hangafter \@ne \hangindent \thr@@ pc \noindent
}
\newcommand*\myNL{\hfill\break}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{Base scenario}
\label{S:Base}

Consider the following:
\begin{flushleft}
    Some text marked~(A)\@.
\end{flushleft}
Not preceded by blank line:\SHOW
\begin{flushleft}
    Some text marked~(B)\@.
\end{flushleft}

Preceded by blank line:\SHOW

\MyParShape
All this is quite OK\@.  This paragraph does have hanging indentation,
but the following one won't\ldots

\ldots as you can see here.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci
elit, ridiculus mus.  Fringilla eius partorietur.



\section{\texttt{flushleft} inside \texttt{flushleft}}
\label{S:fl<fl}

Now consider:
\begin{flushleft}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}
    We nest here the same contruction presented in Section~\ref{S:Base}:
    \begin{flushleft}
        Some text marked~(C)\@.
    \end{flushleft}
    Not preceded by blank line:\SHOW
    \begin{flushleft}
        Some text marked~(D)\@.
    \end{flushleft}

    Preceded by blank line:\SHOW

    \MyParShape
    This paragraph has hanging indentation, but this time the hanging 
    indentation is carried over also to the following one.

    But this could be considered OK\@ too, because, after all, we are still
    inside the \texttt{list} environment implied by the outer
    \texttt{flushleft}: indeed, preserving \verb|\parshape| setting is essential
    for the implementation of ``list-making'' environments.  And
    \texttt{flushleft} environments should \textbf{not} be nested!
\end{flushleft}
Not preceded by blank line:\SHOW

Again, this is what we expect.



\section{\texttt{flushleft} inside \texttt{minipage} inside \texttt{flushleft}}
\label{S:fl<mp<fl}

But consider this other situation:
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.9\linewidth}
        \raggedright % to avoid underfull boxes
        \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}
        Start of the \texttt{minipage}.  Note that \verb|\par| has its primitive
        meaning:\SHOW

        Also here, we nest the same contruction presented in
        Section~\ref{S:Base}:
        \begin{flushleft}
            Some text marked~(E)\@.
        \end{flushleft}
        Not preceded by blank line:\SHOW
        \begin{flushleft}
            Some text marked~(F)\@.
        \end{flushleft}

        Preceded by blank line:\SHOW

        \MyParShape
        As we see, the meaning of \verb|\par| has not reverted to what it was at
        the beginning.  Why is this not good at all?  Well, for a number of
        reasons, of which the fact that hanging indentation is carried over from
        one paragraph to another,\ldots

        (\emph{continuing from the previous paragraph}) \ldots as you can see
        here, is just the first---and rather silly---example that comes to my
        mind.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit, ridiculus
        mus.  Fringilla eius partorietur.

        End of the \texttt{minipage}.
    \end{minipage}

    Thus, we see that, inside the \texttt{minipage}, we do \emph{not} get the
    same behavior as in the ``base scenario'' of Section~\ref{S:Base}, but
    rather the behavior of Section~\ref{S:fl<fl}.
\end{flushleft}

Should this be considered a (tiny) bug in the \LaTeXe\ kernel?



\clearpage

\makeatletter

\def\@minipagerestore{%
    \def\@par{\let\par\@@par\par}
}

\makeatother

\section{Possible fix}
\label{S:Fix}

Consider, finally, what happens now:
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.9\linewidth}
        \raggedright % to avoid underfull boxes
        \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}
        Start of the \texttt{minipage}.  Note that \verb|\par| has its primitive
        meaning:\SHOW

        Once more, we nest here the same contruction presented in
        Section~\ref{S:Base}:
        \begin{flushleft}
            Some text marked~(G)\@.
        \end{flushleft}
        Not preceded by blank line:\SHOW
        \begin{flushleft}
            Some text marked~(H)\@.
        \end{flushleft}

        Preceded by blank line:\SHOW

        \MyParShape
        As we see, this time the meaning of \verb|\par| \emph{has} reverted to
        what it was at the beginning.  Indeed, hanging indentation is no longer
        being carried over from one paragraph to another,\ldots

        (\emph{continuing from the previous paragraph}) \ldots as you can see
        here.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit, ridiculus
        mus.  Fringilla eius partorietur.

        End of the \texttt{minipage}.
    \end{minipage}

    Thus, we see that, inside the \texttt{minipage}, we \emph{do} get, now, the
    same behavior as in the ``base scenario'' of Section~\ref{S:Base}.
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Note that we manually reset `\parindent` in some places to make
the effects of `\@endparenv` visible.  The document you obtain
contains four sections.

**In the first section,** a simple, top-level use of a
`flushleft` environment is exemplified, to serve as a benchmark
for the other cases that are presented below.  Here we see how
the “temporary change” that `\@endarenv` makes to the meaning of
`\par` is undone when it occurs by itself, without a concurrent
“long-term change” being pending.

**The second section** illustrates the case of direct nesting.
The result may look strange at first, but this happens only
because one does not immediately realize that the inner
`flushleft` is actually a second-level list nested within the
first-level list represented by the outer `flushleft`.  Actually,
the typical users will be unaware of this, because they will not
know the details of how `flushleft` is implemented, and the best
advice that could be given to them is to avoid nesting
`center`/`flushleft`/`flushright` environments.

**In the third section,** however, the situation is dimmer:
shouldn’t the `flushleft` environment included in the `minipage`
behave in the same way as the top-level one shown in the first
section, irrespective of the fact that the `minipage` itself is,
in turn, included in another `flushleft` (or `center`, or
`flushright` environment?  Or even in a list?  Actually,
`minipage` resets `\par` to its original meaning, but—aha!—it fails
to similarly reset `\@par`, so that the “long-term change” made
by the outer list percolates, as it were, down to the inner one,
thus determining the same result as in the case of direct
nesting.

Finally, **the fourth section** presents a possible, and even too
obvious fix: include the resetting of `\@par` at the beginning of
`minipage`s.  Here this is done by means of the
`\@minipagerestore` hook.

My question is: is the foregoing analysis correct or not?  And,
connected to this: are there other aspects I have not considered,
which imply that the choice of *not* having the `minipage`
environment redefine `\@par` is intentional?

Comment: Nice question :-).

Comment: I believe that Frank should answer

Comment: @egreg Can you ping Frank? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some Five years later!

There are fifty shades of `\par` in LaTeX!
The OP did a number of tests in my opinion in a very complicated way and concluded
that there might be a bug in LaTeX. Fortunately there is no bug!

The OP based his conclusions that after he inserted a special macro `\MyParshape`, based on `\hangafter\hangindent`, and this carried over
in more paragraphs, this was a possible bug. Had he inserted a `\@@par` in the paragraaph before his
macro at the time everything would have been ok. Now I had to save `\@@par` in the preamble and
use it in the test (since we have the new hook systems now and there are other complications now). In lists this behavior is correct, as there might be more levels of lists and the
program needs to keep the `\par` under control. The OP should have made sure that `\MyParShape`
in a list worked correctly, by defining it appropriately.

I attach the image of my tests and the code. I removed OP's code that was unecessary. We
only need to test for three conditions a) value of `par` in normal paragraphs, its value
in minipages and its value in lists. TEST 9, resolved the OP's question.

By the way the `\par` now has a twin sister, and when we say `\par` we get two!
un-comment  the end of the code below to get a surprise!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.06,0.44,0.08}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MyParShape{%
    \hangafter \@ne \hangindent \thr@@ pc \noindent
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\ATATPAR\@@par
\def\LISTPAR{\if@newlist \advance \par@deathcycles \@ne \ifnum \par@deathcycles >\@m 
\@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }\fi} 
\def\PASS{{\ttfamily\color{green} ~ PASS~}}
\def\FAIL{{\ttfamily\color{red} ~ FAIL~}}
\int_new:N \testcounter
\int_gset:Nn \testcounter{1}
\cs_gset:Npn\TEST #1#2#3
{ \makeatletter
  \int_use:N \testcounter :~~
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1#2{\PASS}{\FAIL}
  {\ttfamily \tl_to_str:n {#3} }
  \int_gincr:N \testcounter
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\subsection*{At start of document}
\TEST{\par}{\@@par}{\par==\@@par}\par
\ExplSyntaxOn
\TEST{\par}{\tex_par:D}{\par != \tex_par:D }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\subsection*{In minipage tests}

\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\TEST{\par}{\ATATPAR}{In minipage \par == \@@par}\par
\end{minipage}

\subsection*{In flushleft tests}
\begin{flushleft}
    \TEST{\par}{\@par}{in flush left \par=\@par (in list definition)}\par
    Some text marked~(A).
\end{flushleft}
\subsection*{Between flush left environments}
\TEST{\par}{\@@par}{between two flush enviroments \par=\@@par l3 wins}  % TEST 5
\makeatother
\begin{flushleft}
    Some text marked~(B).
\end{flushleft}

\subsection*{Nested minipage in flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
\raggedright
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.9\linewidth}
    \makeatletter
       \TEST{\par}{\@@par}{In a list first line of minipage \par=\@@par}\par
   
       \begin{flushleft}
            \TEST{\par}{\@par}{In flusleft>minipage>flushleft \par=\@par (list def.)}
            Some text marked~(E).
        \end{flushleft}
        Not preceded by blank line:\par
        \makeatletter 
        \TEST{\@par}{\LISTPAR}{In list \par=\@par i.e, as defined in lists}
        \makeatother
        \begin{flushleft}
            Some text marked~(F).
        \end{flushleft}
        \MyParShape
        \color{orange}
        As we see, the meaning of \verb|\par| has not reverted to what it was at
        the beginning.  Why is this not good at all?  Well, for a number of
        reasons, of which the fact that hanging indentation is carried over from
        one paragraph to another,\ldots\color{black}\ATATPAR
       
        \makeatletter
        \TEST{\@par}{\LISTPAR}{After \MyParshape \par=\@par=\LISTPAR}
        \makeatother
        
        Continuing from the previous paragraph \ldots as you can see
        here\ldots. There is no issue with the \verb+\MyParShape+!
    \end{minipage}
    
\end{flushleft}


%\ttfamily
%\ExplSyntaxOn
%\meaning\par
%
%
%\meaning\tex_par:D\par
\end{document}
```

[image]