# Formatting - minipage restore indent

Tags: formatting, indentation, minipage

I've some `minipage`in my document and the `parindent` reset automatically in this environment.

After some research, I've found a solution in this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303018/minipage-reset-indent-how-can-i-set-again-to-standard) that I want to improve.

My **goal** :

- Redefine `minipage` to set parindent automatically as proposed by touhami.

My **questions** :

- How change the `minipage` environment (with `\makeatletter`) to redefine preamble of `minipage` as :

```
\saveparinfos
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \useparinfo
    \end{minipage}
```

- Is it bad use to force indent in `minipage` environment and in which case is it wrong ? The [topic here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307235/should-minipage-restore-the-default-definition-of-par) had already asked this question but there are no answer.
- More globally, how/where can I know the details of an environment defined in `LaTeX` in order to change it ? I've already modify some environment defined in package where i could read the code in the documentation but for `minipage` environment, I'm not able to find where this environment is defined.

Thank you for you help and sorry if there is some english mistakes.

**MWE :**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%Command to set indentation in minipage
\newcommand{\saveparinfos}{%
    \edef\myindent{\the\parindent}%
    \edef\myparskip{\the\parskip}}


\newcommand{\useparinfo}{%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\myindent}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}}


\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\subsection{Example of indented text and non-indented in minipage}

    \lipsum[1-2]
    \vspace{0.2cm}

    \noindent\saveparinfos\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        This is a long text to fill the line untill a linebreak appears.

        And there is no indent for each paragraph.
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}\useparinfo
        \lipsum[2]

        And this minipage has indentation for each paragraph.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the source code of LaTeX in [source2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e). In TeX Live, the command `texdoc source2e` opens the corresponding PDF document; then you can use the search function of your PDF viewer or the index to find what you are looking for (e.g., commented source code for `minipage`).

Another way is to look at the file `latex.ltx` that should be part of your TeX distribution, but it has no comments. `latex.ltx` is the compilation of many files, with comments removed. The source file for `minipage` is called `ltboxes.dtx`, you may have it if you have source code for your TeX distribution.

If you look in one of these files, you'll see that `\parindent` and `\parskip` are both set to zero inside a minipage (`\@parboxrestore` is called from `\@iiiminipage`, which is itself called directly and indirectly from `\minipage`). Therefore, if you see indentation for text inside a minipage, it is either *out* of the minipage (which is a box) or has been switched on explicitly inside (these two possibilities are visually different, of course).

I believe the following expanded version of your example should help you understand this and do more or less what you want. Note the use of `\xdef` instead of `\edef` inside the definition of `\saveparinfo`. This way, you can do things like

```
{%
  \parindent=4em\relax
  \saveparinfo{four em}%
  Foo bar.\par}

\useparinfo{four em}%
Etc.
```

which would otherwise cause an error, because with `\edef`, the macros used to store the saved parameters would only be defined inside the group. `\xdef` makes these macros `\global`, just like macros defined with `\newcommand`. Now, the full example I promised. :-)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter

% Command to save \parindent and \parskip under a specific key. The argument
% is the key and can even contain non-letters (e.g., hyphens or spaces).
\newcommand*{\saveparinfo}[1]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname my@#1@parindent\endcsname{\the\parindent}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname my@#1@parskip\endcsname{\the\parskip}%
}

% Restore parameters that were saved under the specified key.
\newcommand*{\useparinfo}[1]{%
  \parindent=\csname my@#1@parindent\endcsname \relax
  \parskip=\csname my@#1@parskip\endcsname \relax
}

\makeatother

% Like minipage, but suppresses indentation if used in vertical mode (i.e.,
% before a paragraph has been started).
\newenvironment{myMinipage}{%
  % If we are about to start a paragraph, the indentation box will be *out*
  % of the minipage -> empty it first.
  \noindent
  \minipage    % like \begin{minipage} but gives nicer error handling here
}{%
  \endminipage % ditto for \end{minipage}
}

\newcommand*{\nextSample}{\bigskip\filbreak}


\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\subsection{Example of indented text and non-indented in minipage}

\lipsum[1-2]
\bigskip

\parindent=0pt\relax % Suppress paragraph indentation and save parameters
\saveparinfo{zero}%
No indentation. We saved the \verb|\parindent| and \verb|\parskip| parameters
under key \texttt{zero}.
\nextSample

\begin{myMinipage}{\linewidth}
  This is a long text to fill the line until a linebreak appears. Bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

  And there is no indentation for any paragraph.
\end{myMinipage}
\nextSample

\parindent=1em\relax
\saveparinfo{oneem}%
Now, paragraphs are indented. We saved the \verb|\parindent| and
\verb|\parskip| parameters under key \texttt{oneem}. Bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

Another paragraph with the same parameters. Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\nextSample

\begin{myMinipage}{\linewidth}
  Here, paragraphs are not indented. \lipsum[1]

  Other paragraph inside the minipage. No indentation.
\end{myMinipage}
\nextSample

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-\parindent} % real minipage environment
  Here, the whole minipage is preceded by an indentation box, but there is
  no indentation for paragraphs \emph{inside} the minipage.

  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\nextSample

\begin{myMinipage}{\linewidth}\useparinfo{zero}%
  This minipage starts at the left margin and has no indentation for its
  paragraphs (this was restored using key \texttt{zero}).

  \lipsum[1]
\end{myMinipage}
\nextSample

\begin{myMinipage}{\linewidth}\useparinfo{oneem}%
  This minipage starts at the left margin and has one em indentation for
  each paragraph (this was restored using key \texttt{oneem}).

  \lipsum[1]
\end{myMinipage}
\end{document}
```

### Page 1

[image: Page 1]

### Page 2

[image: Page 2]

### Page 3

[image: Page 3]

Comment: I fixed the comment before the definition of `\saveparinfos` . You can even use non-letters in key names; for instance, key `one-em` or even `one em` (with a space inside) would have been fine!

Comment: I also switched to using `\xdef` instead of `\edef` when defining the macros where parameters are saved (e.g., `\my@zero@parindent`, `\my@zero@parskip`). This will be useful if you call `\useparinfo` in a scope (group) that is not “visible” from where `\saveparinfos` was called (e.g., if `\useparinfo` is called at outer scope with a given key, while `\saveparinfos` was called earlier with the same key *but* inside a group).

Comment: I renamed `\saveparinfos` to `\saveparinfo` for consistency with `\useparinfo`...

Comment: After a while, i'm back, sorry for the delayed answer while you completely answered my ask. Do you know if there is a reason why the `minipage` has been configured to set to zero `\parindent` and `\parskip` ?

Comment: What a pleasant surprise. :-) I suppose that for the typical layout work `minipage` was developed for, `\parindent` is more often a nuisance than something desirable. TeX's `\vbox` is similar to `minipage` in some respects but does honour `\parindent`. Try this: `\parindent=1em \setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{Really, I like}\par \hbox{them!}}---\vbox{\hsize=15em I like \box0 \ paragraph indentation boxes a lot.}`.